# Elixir app on VPS can't started from ssh on daemon mode

Tags: elixir, distillery

I've been built an app with Phoenix + Elixir and deploy it to server with distillery.
Everything worked fine, until I try to create some bash script to automate deployment, FYI: I've been tried edeliver but it didn't fit my need.
I'm always successful when try to run app on daemon mode on my VPS when I logged on and run

```
sudo my_app/bin/app start
```

But, when I run ssh with remote command

```
ssh user@some_ip -C "sudo my_app/bin/app start"
```

It failed to start with no output on the shell screen. It just won't worked.

But, if I run on foreground mode with

```
ssh user@some_ip -C "sudo my_app/bin/app foreground"
```

It will be successful start the app and show the running log
I've been trying using `nohup` on foreground mode but it still showing the running log, while I need to run another command

Is there any required step to run SSH remote command, some environment set maybe ?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Running a remote with plain `bin/app start` is a very bad idea in the first place. One should use either `upstart` or `systemd` (or another process scheduler) to ensure the application will be up and running after it’s started. Once properly set, you’ll execute something like `ssh user@some_ip -C "sudo systemctl start app"` and the glitch you  currently experience should just go away.

Comment: Yeah, `systemd` is working for me. Thank you very much @mudasobwa

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa could you post it as answer, So I could choose it as accepted answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Running a remote with plain `bin/app start` is a very bad idea in the first place. One should use either `upstart` or `systemd` (or another process scheduler) to ensure the application will be up and running after it’s started.

Once properly set, you’ll execute something like

```
ssh user@some_ip -C "sudo systemctl start app"
```

and the glitch you currently experience should just go away.

Answer (score 0):

Do you normally have to type in a password when you run `sudo`? If so, that could cause a problem with SSH. You can try running SSH with a pseudotty so you can type in the sudo password i.e. `ssh -t user@some_ip -C "sudo my_app/bin/app start"`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem since OP says `ssh user@some_ip -C "sudo my_app/bin/app foreground"` works fine.

Comment: the user need no password on running `sudo` command, 
last time I've tried an brand new app with `--no-ecto` command and facing the same issue